# (Javascript Audio start/stop at specific time each day) Audio start at 5am and ends 10 mins after

Tags: javascript, audio

I have the code below, but I am unsure how to get the sound to stop playing 10 minutes after 5am.

So hits 5am, audio starts playing fine, I don't know how to make the audio stop once it hits 5am and then the next day it will repeat the cycle.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');

function updateTime(){
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

  if (hours == 5 && minutes == 0) {
     audio.play();

    setTimeout(function() { audio.pause(); }, 8.28e+7);
}
}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

</script>
```

Help Please and thanks.
:)

Answer (score 2):

`8.28e+7` is `1380` minutes... that's nearly a full day - not 10 minutes!

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { audio.pause(); }, 600000);
```

---

You should also note that because your interval is running every 1 second, your setTimeout function will be called up to 59 times. I would recommend using an `isPlaying` flag.

For example:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
var isPlaying = false;

function updateTime(){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

    if (!isPlaying && hours == 5 && minutes == 0) {
        audio.play();
        isPlaying = true;
        setTimeout(function() { audio.pause(); isPlaying = false; }, 600000);
    }
}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```